# Theory of GOD from Ramcharitmanas? No date of end of world theory

Tags: ramayana, rama, ramcharitmanas

What is theory of GOD as per Ramcharitamanasa?

> Jake bal biracnhi hari isa
>   palat srujat harat dasasisa

Sunderkanda

Means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many [prophecies](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/List_of_predictions_of_the_end_of_the_world) of end of the world. But as per Ramcharitmanasa Lord Rama is Human form of Vishnu and because of his will power or desire Lord Vishnu Lord Shiva and Lord Brahma generates operates and destroys the world. It is written in hindi lines by Sage tulsidas.

> by whose might, O ten-headed monster, Brahma, Hari (Vishnu) and Isha(Shiva) carry on their respective function of creation, preservation and destruction;

Actually these deities manifest in some human to do the work of deities. Such humans face mental disorders like bipolar mood disorders.

We can not deny power of any deity or goddess but when they appear / manifest in our body we can feel the power of them.

Generally this happens when elections are near. It is very sophisticated time for patients like this.

When the psychotic disorder event happens, the patient see animals. for example if the patient is praying to shiva he will see nandi near his area of location. Otherwise birds try to show him way.

Another theory is Lord is making Nimitta and doing his works by giving spiritual powers to patient. Patient will see minor tragedies or chamatkars and by fear will chant Lord's name more.

In this time babies are born, old people dies and big events occur in world. I feel no shame if someone downvote as this is experience based answer but I feel to share it.

**Note: Chanting Lord's name is good upto some extent like 12-14 hours. Exceeding that will lead one to disorders.**

Comment: The exact translation of verse is  **by whose might, O ten-headed monster,
Brahma, Hari (Vishnu) and Isha(Shiva) carry on their respective function of creation,
preservation and destruction;** denoting Lord Rama is supreme (By Hanuman)..

Comment: Please edit the answer as per your translation in comment.

Comment: You already have that meaning in your answer..... I only wrote just to make other know the exact Verse Translation....